# Access extended component's method from its parent in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, abstract-class, angular-content-projection

I'm building a dynamic wizard component in Angular. I want the component to be smart so that the user has no configuration to handle, all one has to do is to call the wizard from a component and provide its steps components like so:

```html
<wizard>
    <wizard-step>
        <select-fruit></select-fruit>
    </wizard-step>
    <wizard-step>
        <quantity></quantity>
    </wizard-step>
</wizard>
```

I am using:

```
@ContentChildren(WizardFullPageStepComponent)
public stepComponents: QueryList<WizardFullPageStepComponent>;
```

To dynamically get the steps and initialize the wizard's logic.
The `select-fruit` and `quantity` components extend a generic component:

```
@Component({
    selector: "av-wizard-generic-step",
    template: ""
})
export abstract class WizardGenericStep {
    abstract isValid(): void;
}
```

```
@Component({
    selector: "select-fruit",
    template: "Nice fruit"
})
export class FruitStepComponent{
    public isValid(): void {
        console.log("is the fruit is valid")
    }
}
```

I would like to implement the logic in the `wizard-step` component to be able to call the extended implemented `isValid()` method (here from `FruitStepComponent`) so that depending on the current step shown, the expected method is called.

To keep the component as generic as possible, I do not want to refer to the extended components but only the generic one:

```
@Component({
    selector: "av-wizard-full-page-step",
    templateUrl: "./wizard-full-page-step.component.html"
})
export class WizardFullPageStepComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    @Input()
    public showStep: boolean = false;

    @ContentChild("content", { static: false })
    public wizardGenericStep: WizardGenericStep;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        // here this.wizardGenericStep is undefined
    }
}
```

I have tried the previous solution, but the value is undefined. How can I accomplish this? Is there a components' tree injector I could use maybe? I would be good with an ugly solution, as the logic of the wizard component will be hidden from the used.